# Where can I download a shared userdata folder which has unlock all feaures?

Tags: plants-vs-zombies

I've finished everything in the Normal edition. I now just enjoy playing the Endless Survival with the GotY edition. But to play with the new edition, I have to replay from the beginning - which is quite boring!

So, I want to look for saved userdata from any of you who have unlocked everything in GotY edition. I can't find a shared userdata which has all plants/mini-games unlocked, all shop's plants bought? Please share if you have one.

Comment: If you are playing Endless Survival, you will be able to buy everything soon enough.

Comment: @users who have voted me down: I have edited my quesiton to make clear about the reason why I'm looking for this!

Comment: That is a much more clear and legitimate reason. However, that means you already have one! Take your data folder from the old version and paste it in the new one. Since Steam upgraded everyone to the GOTY edition from normal, I know they are compatible. Everything I had transfered just fine. For reference, see http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/6973/ someone else has already tried this as well.

Comment: @WillfulZizard: I've tried but the saved game doesn't work for me in Windows XP. Will again try in Windows 7.

Answer (score 3):

You can find such a file [here](http://www.cheathappens.com/show_download.asp?ID=26069).

> 9999 ~ sun, 9999 ~ money, 9999 ~ fertilizer, 9999 ~ bug spray, 9999 ~ chocolate, 9999 ~ tree food, 100% Complete, Gold Flower unlocked, 201 Feet Tall Tree of Wisdom.

Comment: I recommend you provide a direct link. As long as we're in beta, it's actually better to surface potential issues! Anyway the only meta question I can find regarding cheats is [this](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/489/how-do-we-stand-on-cheats-in-particularly-for-multiplayer-games).

Comment: Our only real policy against linking is "It can't be illegal content", as per [Jeff here](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/266/should-we-allow-links-to-abandonware-game-sites/267#267). Past that, if it is merely questionable then that is an exercise of the user to decide whether to follow (and you should provide ample warning in your body to aid in such a decision).

Comment: @Oak: complete.

Comment: I tried this on my Win XP pc. It doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to restart your game when you switch to the Game of the Year edition.  Your savegame file will work just fine.